# Static data served from AngularJS Service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I have a couple relatively large javascript objects that I use to help out with data bindings, layout of the page and a lot of logic in the controller. I have moved these objects in a service. For instance, here's an abbreviated example:

```
        getEntityTypes: function() {
            return [{ 
                displayName: "User", 
                value: "users"
            }, {
                displayName: "Group", 
                value: "groups"
            }, {
                displayName: "Section",
                value: "sections"
            }];
        }
```

Previously, I've had all these objects defined in the controller. My main question is, will the controller get these staticly defined objects in a synchronous fashion? Or do I need to give it a callback and treat it as if it's an asynchronous request (like if its making a http.get request) Or can I do something like this:

```
$scope.entityTypes = coolService.getEntityTypes();
```

And then I can immediately do stuff with `$scope.entityTypes`?

I am currently relying on `$scope.entityTypes` within the callback of a web request, so it's not causing me any problems, but I'm not sure if this is like a bad idea or not?

Any advice is helpful,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controller will receive the objects in a synchronous manner.
In its root, these are basically method calls between two objects.

Comment: Awesome, thank you, I was relying on this assumption in a lot my logic. I can feel confident about it now :)